# Rules for a group in openerp 7

Tags: rules, openerp-7, usergroups

I have inherited project task module and created a group 'Inspector'.
I need to create a rule, when a inspector logged in, see tasks that assigned to him only. I created a rule is given below:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="project_inspector_project_tasks_rule">          
<field name="name">Inspector Project  Tasks</field>
<field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="model_project_task"/>
<field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=','user.id')]</field>
</record>
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In domain has following syntax:

```
[('field_name', 'operator', 'field_value')]
```

In your case, field_value will be integer. You given value as a string.

Try with this code:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="project_inspector_project_tasks_rule">          
    <field name="name">Inspector Project  Tasks</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_task"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks Odedra, i have tried that too, but it didn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer please try with it. I have improve *ref* attribute.

Comment: I removed value 'Employee' and set Null for Human resource in Settings ->Users -> Application. Then it works.